# Start a fire in 4-restaurant

Tags: cat-simulator-2015

The fire starts if the "Hells Kitchen!" combo is shown, scoring 5000 points. It appeared if all the three bottles are thrown in any order, but not in the newest version of the game.

**Main question:** In the video game Cat Simulator 2015, how do I get a "Hells Kitchen!" combo in the level 4-restaurant?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the impossibility to get this combo is a bug in this game, so the game certainly needs updates. However, I'm not able to update this game on my tablet.

Comment: What do you base this assessment on, do you have any sources for it?

Comment: I'm playing this game on my tablet "Prestigio" (almost) everyday.

Comment: This mission gives 2 diamonds and takes one of the three mission slots. If I complete this mission, I could get diamonds up tp 50% faster. Also I couldn't get 150 coins when doing this mission repeadetly.